# Converting JSON into classes in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, api, json.net

I'm pulling data from Google's waypoint API and the JSON data returned looks like  [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=London&destination=Manchester&waypoints=via:Leeds|via:Rochdale).
I have used Visual Studio's paste special to create the class:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property geocoded_waypoints() As Geocoded_Waypoints
    Public Property routes() As Route
    Public Property status As String
End Class

Public Class Geocoded_Waypoints
    Public Property geocoder_status As String
    Public Property place_id As String
    Public Property types() As String
End Class

Public Class Route
    Public Property bounds As Bounds
    Public Property copyrights As String
    Public Property legs() As Leg
    Public Property overview_polyline As Overview_Polyline
    Public Property summary As String
    Public Property warnings() As Object
    Public Property waypoint_order() As Object
End Class

Public Class Bounds
    Public Property northeast As Northeast
    Public Property southwest As Southwest
End Class

Public Class Northeast
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class

Public Class Southwest
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class

Public Class Overview_Polyline
    Public Property points As String
End Class

Public Class Leg
    Public Property distance As Distance
    Public Property duration As Duration
    Public Property end_address As String
    Public Property end_location As End_Location
    Public Property start_address As String
    Public Property start_location As Start_Location
    Public Property steps() As _Step
    Public Property traffic_speed_entry() As Object
    Public Property via_waypoint() As Via_Waypoint
End Class

Public Class Distance
    Public Property text As String
    Public Property value As Integer
End Class

Public Class Duration
    Public Property text As String
    Public Property value As Integer
End Class

Public Class End_Location
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class

Public Class Start_Location
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class

Public Class _Step
    Public Property distance As Distance1
    Public Property duration As Duration1
    Public Property end_location As End_Location1
    Public Property html_instructions As String
    Public Property polyline As Polyline
    Public Property start_location As Start_Location1
    Public Property travel_mode As String
    Public Property maneuver As String
End Class

Public Class Distance1
    Public Property text As String
    Public Property value As Integer
End Class

Public Class Duration1
    Public Property text As String
    Public Property value As Integer
End Class

Public Class End_Location1
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class

Public Class Polyline
    Public Property points As String
End Class

Public Class Start_Location1
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class

Public Class Via_Waypoint
    Public Property location As Location
    Public Property step_index As Integer
    Public Property step_interpolation As Single
End Class

Public Class Location
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lng As Single
End Class
```

I am trying to convert the JSON data into this class using:

```
Dim client as new WebClient()
Dim client_Stream As Stream = client.OpenRead(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=London&destination=Manchester&waypoints=via:Leeds|via:Rochdale)
Dim streamreading As New StreamReader(client_Stream)
Dim JSON_str As String = streamreading.ReadToEnd()
Dim temp_json As JSON_data.Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_data.Rootobject)(JSON_str)
streamreading.Close()
```

But it throws this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Tester.JSON_data.Geocoded_Waypoints' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'geocoded_waypoints', line 2, position 28.'
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All the robots are imperfect.  Change the array declarations to `Public Property routes As Route()` for instance (all of them can be List()f T) instead).  You can also collapse classes like `Northeast` and `Soiuthwest` which are obvious repeats to a single one such as `Direction`.  I would sample some other results to find out what those `As Object` properties really are.  `Waypoint_Order` *seems* like it might be integer, `warnings As String()` but no idea about `traffic_speed_entry`

Comment: @Plutonix Changed `routes` as recommended and also tried to find some examples of `warnings`, `waypoint_order` and `traffic_speed_entry` but found none. There was no change to the error message